# Display a div with images and hyperlinks on top of a nested div upon clicking or on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a div tag of this nature:

```
<td>
  <a href="" style="text-decoration: none">
  <div id="navigation_div">
     <div class="functiontitle">
        <font face="helvetica" color="darkgreen"><b><center>Revenues & Expenses</center> </b>        </font>                   
     </div>
     <div class="summary">
        <font face="arial" color="black"><center>At-a-glance and detailed information on  all revenues and expenses incurred</center></font>
     </div>
     <div class="functionimage">
         <img src="../../common/images/revenue_expenses.png" width="60" height="60" style="margin:-18px 2px 6px 9px;"/>
     </div>
  </div>  
  </a> 
</td>
```

The CSS for the above code fragment is:

```
#navigation_div{
   height: 165px;
   width: 195px;
   align:center;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #eef3fa; 
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eef3fa, #DBE2DC); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eef3fa, #DBE2DC); 
   border: 2px solid #787878;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px rgb(204, 204, 204) inset;
 }

#navigation_div:hover{  
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px rgb(204, 254, 204) inset;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.functiontitle{
   margin-top:10px;
 }

.summary{
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-bottom:22px;
}

.functionimage{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 2px;
   margin-right: 2px;
   margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

What I am looking for is when I onClick() on the #navigation_div, the #navigation_div should look a bit lightblack in color(May be using opacity) with the content in the #navigation_div clearly visible && I should get two images(Revenues and Expenses) with which if i click on either of the image, it should go to either revenue.php or expense.php

The outcome that I am intending to have at the end of this is depicted in this 2 images which I have placed it here:
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=8140319629414
http://www.imagesup.net/?di=414031962941

Comment: Have you even tried creating your own solution? This is quite simple with jQuery.

Comment: If you dont need any further javascript and if you are not optimizing for ie8, you can also use the css pseudo selecto :target

Comment: @fpsColton Since I am new to Jquery, I am wondering on how to achieve that. Any suggestions?

Comment: @gulty Can you modify my code and elaborate so that I could get what you are trying to convey...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your submenu elements with the style `display:none;` before your `functionimage`

Then add a jQuery selector to bind your click event or hover event, depending on which one you want:

```
$('#navigation_div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.subitem').css('display','block');
});
```

If you want them to disappear again when you mouseout, you can do this:

```
$('#navigation_div').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.subitem').css('display','block');
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.subitem').css('display','none');
});
```

For the overlay, just create an .overlay css class that overrides the box-shadow:

```
.overlay
{  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px rgb(0,0,0) inset !important;
}
```

And add it to the element in your event:

```
$(this).addClass('overlay');
```

**Edit: see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYd4b/)**

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and I think what you are saying would indeed work for me... But when I modified the codes as per according to your suggestions, I don't get anything. Is it possible for you to re-post my code with your modifications.

Comment: @Naseem I've added a jsfiddle example

Comment: Awesome dude!!!That was what I intended for and you had completed my task with very ease without any further work on my part. Once again Thanx...

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quick solution in jsfiddle, which might help you get started. It is an image; onClick, displays an overlaid div with links on it. The backdrop has some `padding` to show that they are indeed seperate, but if you remove that and tweak the `margin-left` of `.overlay` a little bit, it should be perfect. Hope that helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/WLXL6/2/

Comment: Its more or less what I was intending but if you consider your code fragment, its not working to my expectations.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Specifically, how is it functionally not doing what you were expecting? (Other than the point the links don't direct you to php files yet.) I'd be happy to work with you further, but I need more feedback in order to improve the result :)

Comment: If you can refer my post above and observe that there are 2 images which I had placed to elaborate on my expectation. As per to your solution, its not complying. But I am very thankful to you for your eagerness to help me. And speaking of this particular post, I have got the solution.